# How to remove Pandas Series name from plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
data.groupby('parental level of education')['gender'].count().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.1f%%', title='Population Composition',fontsize=10)
```

The following code plots a pie chart which has the name written 'gender' on the plot. I want to remove that. How do I do that? [Pie Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edAOL.png)

Comment: One line of code is not enough. You need to provide a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example), please.

Comment: Import matplotlib.pyplot as plt and then after the pandas plot call, you can use plt.xlabel('') to set the x-axis label to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

By setting the y-axis label with empty string.

```py
ax=data.groupby('parental level of education')['gender'].count().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.1f%%', title='Population Composition',fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel('')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be automatically passing gender as a kwarg. Quite a roundabout way but this works.

```
s = data.groupby('parental level of education')['gender'].count()
s.name = ""
s.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.1f%%', title='Population Composition',fontsize=10)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But yes, doesn't look very pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

The series name goes into the `ylabel` argument of the `plot()`. This can be used (as suggested in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098937/7041244)) when calling the `plot()` function.

For your question, this goes something like

```py
data.groupby('parental level of education')['gender'].count().plot(
kind='pie', 
autopct='%.1f%%', 
title='Population Composition',
fontsize=10, 
ylabel='') ## Here is the change :P
```

Comment: This gives `TypeError: pie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ylabel'` error

Comment: Which version of pandas and matplotlib are you using ?